Understanding the inconsistent size of HashMap in a multithreaded Java program
I have a multithreaded Java program where each thread is inserting unique keys into a shared HashMap. However, when I check the size of the HashMap after all threads have finished executing, the size is not consistent with the expected number of insertions.
Here's the code:
public class CurrentHashMapDemo {
    private static final int NUM_THREADS = 5;
    private static final int NUM_INSERTIONS = 100;
    private static HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
        for(int i=0; i< NUM_THREADS; i++){
            executorService.execute(insertRecord());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        if(!executorService.isTerminated()){
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        System.out.println("Size of the hashmap="+ hashMap.size());
    }

    private static Runnable insertRecord(){
        return () -> {
            for(int i=0; i<NUM_INSERTIONS; i++){
                System.out.println("Key:"+ i+Thread.currentThread().getName());
                hashMap.put(i+Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
            }
        };
    }
}

In this code, each thread is inserting NUM_INSERTIONS number of records into the HashMap. The key for each record is a combination of the loop index i and the name of the current thread, which should be unique for each thread.
However, when I print the size of the HashMap after all threads have finished executing, the size is not consistently NUM_THREADS * NUM_INSERTIONS. I understand that HashMap is not thread-safe, and I know that I could use ConcurrentHashMap to solve this issue. But I’m interested in understanding where exactly the race condition is occurring in the HashMap implementation that’s causing this inconsistent behavior.
I’m using OpenJDK 17. Can anyone explain where this race condition might be happening in this specific JDK’s HashMap implementation and how it’s affecting the size of the HashMap?
Can anyone explain where this race condition might be happening and how it's affecting the size of the HashMap?
Thank @user85421  for your comment, I was looking for the same,
one possibility: the hash map is created with a capacity of 16, when this is exhausted, it must be reorganized (resized) - if two threads do that concurrently, something might (will) get messed up
Note for everyone is is reading the question, Here I understand we can not use the Hashmap, but we need to use the ConcurrentHashMap, However, through this question, I only want to understand why Hashmap was not able to generate a consistent size. This might be due to rehashing.
If I use the following ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap all problems get resolved.
 private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

Here I need to understand why we can't use HashMap, and why it not behaving correctly in multithreaded environment.

HashMap is not thread safe. This is one of the things that might happen when things that are not thread safe are used by multiple threads.

In which HashMap implementation? There is potentially one per JDK version and perhaps one per patch release, and different ones per JVM vendor. And there are probably several failure sites, not just one. The only salient point is that it isn’t thread-safe. Period. Your question is too open-ended to answer.

concurrenthashmap. So why aren't you using ConcurrentHashMap?

one possibility: the hash map is created with a capacity of 16, when this is exhausted, it must be reorganized (resized) - if two threads do that concurrently, something might (will) get messed up

Hint: synchronizedMap()

@user207421 I have added JDV version.

synchronized (hashMap) { hashMap.put(i+Thread.currentThread().getName(), i); } Also, it would be a good idea to test the result of Map.put

I'm curious: why do you want to know where the specific race condition is?  Is this just personal knowledge or do you think you can do something about it in a production code base?

It doesn’t matter how many versions you add. Your question is based on a false premiss. There is no such thing as ‘this race condition’ here. The entire thing isn’t thread-safe. Not just one line of code.

private static Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<>(); ... Size of the hashmap=500

I'm going to ask again why?  The current implementation of HashMap is a monstrous ~2600 line file that won't be fun to trace through.  What is the actual need here that you must know the answer to this?  As user207421 said it doesn't matter, there's just too many possibilities and nothing can be done about it.

@user207421  for(int i=0; i<NUM_INSERTIONS; i++){
System.out.println("Key:"+ i+Thread.currentThread().getName());
hashMap.put(i+Thread.currentThread().getName(), i);
}   here is codesegment which I want to understand    i+Thread.currentThread().getName(),  key will different for each thread   in hashmap it   it should there will be no collision and overridden so why it not give the size as 500

see my comment -- adding to the comment: even if one thread is resizing the hash map, data put by a second thread will eventually get lost

Because the class isn’t thread-safe. You already know that. It’s pointless to just  keep restating your question, and it’s pointless to expect us to keep restating our answers.

@user85421  Thank you, I understood, can you create the answer, so that I can understood.

key will different for each thread in hashmap it it should there will be no collision No that's not how hashmaps work.  Given different keys, the resulting index of a hash map could be the same as a previous (different) key.  The hash map implements a list to hold multiple keys if this happens.

@user207421 what am I trying "to sell"?? What "it isn't" ??

@user207421 I wrote "one possibility: ..." -- should not be interpreted as "the only possibility", actually it should be giving the idea that there are more possibilities, like in "one of many" !

@user85421  Thanks I will try to rephrase the question, Thank you for understanding the problem,  I was looking for the same.

Basically if you were going to create a thread-safe hash map class you would have to either sprinkle synchronized everywhere, like HashTable, or else use a different technique altogether, like ConcurrentHashMap’s copy-on-write. It is futile to look for a monocausal explanation as you have been.

another possibility, not the only one, for Java 21: after reaching some size (bin count >= 8) the map will use tree instead of list for  a bin. Again, if one thread is put a value while another thread is converting the bin to tree, eventually the value will get lost.

It's.. everywhere, really.
Here's the simple and seemingly surprisingly rule:
Accessing a field from 2 threads is completely broken and results in an application whose behaviour is arbitrary and untestable.
That sounds drastic, doesn't it? And yet, this really is how it works. So, what 'causes' this behaviour of hashmap? Well, just open the source of hashmap. Look at all those fields. Look at how the methods you are invoking, such as put, touch those fields. As per the rule above, vola. the behaviour is arbitrary, and thus untestable. But it'll fail on you. If not sooner, then later, but, fail it will.
This drastic state of affairs isn't to annoy you. It's because that's how computers really work. These days, a CPU cannot even access main memory. No ability to that, whatsoever. Instead, CPUs can only access local caches. These are one page's worth (pages are 64k to 128k or so generally) of contiguous memory, and they are a copy - independent from main memory; modify main memory and this cached page will not change. Modify the cache and main memory does not change. This is for simple and obvious physics reasons. Go look at a CPU. Look at where the memory is. Get out a ruler. Oh deary me that's a humongous ocean of a gap between those two. Speed of light isn't infinite, you know! Just sending a signal alllllllll the way from a CPU to that memory bank? Good grief. That CPU could be doing hundreds of instructions in that time. Hold on, we have to even wait for that signal to travel allll the way back? Unacceptable!
So how does a CPU access main memory? It asks the memory controller to evict one of its cache pages (write the whole thing back into main memory, all 64k/128k of it), then copy a page of main memory into this cache page. Again, the whole lot - these architectures do that as fast as 1 byte so no point even building a system to let you more fine-grainedly control what needs copying. Then the CPU core will find some thumbs and intently twiddle them for 500 to a 1000 cycles. Because that's going to take oodles of time.
Of course, CPUs aren't guaranteed to work this way, and in practice the amount of cache pages available is quite limited; a CPU may have to 'evict' a page halfway through an operation. That'll cause slowdowns, and causes something to be written into main memory. It's extremely difficult to try to predict exactly what, if multiple cores all have different versions of the same region of main memory. Which core evicts first, which evicts last? Who knows?
Java couldn't possibly manage to run fast unless it adopted a memory model that is compatible with all this. Hence, the simple but seemingly drastic rule: Accessing a field from 2 threads is completely broken and results in an application whose behaviour is arbitrary and untestable.
One field can have 10 different values simultaneously; each thread has its own copy. Or not. And you have no control nor any idea when a thread will make its copy, when (or if!) it will flush that copy back to main mem.
But wait! The JMM's Happens Before rules!
The JMM is the Java Memory Model; it describes not so much 'how java works' (because locking down how it works means, if that particular way of working is inefficient on some architecture, that java either cannot run on that architecture, or runs badly - and we can't have that!) - but more 'these limited things are guaranteed by the JVM. The rest aint - you're going to have to make it work reliably working solely with the guarantees we prove here in the JMM section'.
The above section describes mostly what is not guaranteed. So let's get to what is guaranteed: Happens-Before relationships.
This is an explicitly enumerated list that establishes 'HB' between 2 bytecode instructions. If HB(A, B) is established, where A and B are bytecode instructions:

B cannot observe any field in a state that it was prior to A having finished. In other words, if A writes a value to a field, B cannot observe the old value.
Note that it's not about 'it guarantees B happens after A'. It merely guarantees that B cannot observe previous state. For example, if B doesn't look at any field A modifies, then the JVM is free to run B first and A later.
It doesn't necessarily work the other way around.
Timing is explicitly excluded. If you can figure out how certain things were based on how long some segment of code runs, that's not a beach of the guarantees stipulated in the JMM.

So, what establishes HB?

The 'natural' / 'obvious': if A and B are executed by the same thread, then the code itself establishes an order in which that code is executed, and HB(A, B) exists for all of it. In other words, given int x = 5; x = 10; int z = x;, z cannot possibly be 5, because all 3 statements are HB due to all being run by the same thread. This is.. obvious, but note that in int x = 5; int y = 10; int z = x; int a = y;, the system is free to execute int y = 10; first, then int a = y;, then int x = 5;, then int z = x;. Will it? Probably not. But a JVM that does, wouldn't be breaking the rules: Because int a = y; doesn't observe the fact that int x = 5; hasn't run yet, the JMM is adhered to.
Thread management: t.start(); is HB relative to the first line in the run() block of that thread. Also, the last line executed by a thread is HB relative to another thread executing t.join().
synchronized. 2 blocks of code each having a synchronized (x) where x refers to the same object will figure out some ordering. The last statement executed in that block by whatever thread 'goes first' is HB relative to the first line in the other thread.
volatile also does, but it can be difficult to figure out which thread was 'first' in this story.
A bunch of other more exotic things that you tend not to run into.

So, how do you even 'chat' between threads, given that you can't touch fields? By ensuring that there is clear HB for every such interaction. Anytime one thread writes and another reads, you really, really want HB somewhere in that otherwise what you read is a coin toss. And not a fair coin either - an evil coin; your code works every time for 3 weeks and then starts failing just as you are giving that important demo to the big customer.
Of course, most of the classes in the java.util.concurrent package establish HB all over the place. Read the java docs carefully - it is pointless to attempt to analyse what they guarantee by inspecting the code and reasoning out how the JMM applies to it and which guarantees you can glean from that. No - just read the javadoc, they list the guarantees in their own terms. More reliable (code can change, javadoc guarantees as a rule don't, as that would be a breaking change), much simpler to understand. Point is, the code delivers on those guarantees by establishing HB.

Here I understand we can not use the Hashmap, but we need to use the ConcurrentHashMap, However, through this question, I only want to understand why Hashmap was not able to generate a consistent size. This might be due to rehashing.  This answer is not making any sense, for my question.

The reason it doesn't make sense >to you< is that you don't understand the JMM.  Learn about the JMM first.  Then the answer will make sense.

Good explanation, but some numbers seem a tad high? For instance: "Just sending a signal alllllllll the way from a CPU to that memory bank? Good grief. That CPU could be doing hundreds of instructions in that time." The speed of light is about 0.3 m/ns. At a clock rate of 3 GHz, light therefore travels about 0.1 m per clock cycle, so 100 clock cycles would be 10 meters. Most computers have their main memory a little closer than that ;-)

You're ignoring capacitance on the bus, delays in the decoding logic of the VMU unit and the memory itself, delay needed to allow signals to synchronize, possible reflections on the bus (which also might need delays to stabilize), the possibility that someone else (DMA?) might be using the bus when the CPU wants to, etc.  The CPU does NOT simply shine a flashlight on the memory cell it needs to access, it doesn't work anything like that.

@NeelabhSingh apparently you are looking for a single simple answer: "Here on this line, without concurrenthashmap this thing just generates a random number and tada that is why you get fluctuating numbers here". It's not that simple. This answer is the reason. If you cannot understand it, read it again. If you still can't understand it, learn about CPU architectures, or fully read the JMM, though, that's much heavier reading than this answer

Volatile only establishes a HB between a write to the variable and subsequent reads from that variable.

This is just to turn what everyone is saying (correctly!) in the comments into an Answer.  (Since you seem to want one ...)
The problem with your demo code is that it is not thread-safe.  You have multiple threads that are updating a shared object (a HashMap) instance which is specified to be non-thread-safe.  That will lead to unspecified behavior.  The javadoc states:

Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

The exact (detailed) cause of the inconsistent behavior that you are seeing is immaterial.  The real answer on the cause would require a detailed analysis of a ~2600 line HashMap class to identify the point (or points) at which memory anomalies would occur in the map ... when used in the incorrect way that you are using it.  And even that wouldn't give a certain answer1.
Your arguments that the demo "should work because " are flying in the face of the evidence that it doesn't work!  And they are ignoring the fact that the javadoc for HashMap is (in effect) saying that it may  not work.

This might be due to rehashing.

It might, in some cases, but see above.  We are not going to speculate on the causes for you because they would just be guesses2.
The fix (in a real application) would be to either synchronize the HashMap externally, or use a ConcurrentHashMap.

1 - If you really think that knowing what is happening is going to help you, feel free to 1) study the specification for the Java Memory Model (JMM) so that you fully understand it, then 2) analyze the HashMap source code in the light of the JMM.
2 - Guesses about the behavior of concurrent code are notorious for being wrong ... at least some of the time.

Here I understand we can not use the Hashmap, but we need to use the ConcurrentHashMap, However, through this question, I only want to understand why Hashmap was not able to generate a consistent size. This might be due to rehashing.  This the only I need to understand,

You DO NOT need to understand.  Seriously.  And if you do, see footnote 1.  Please don't expect someone else to do a huge amount of (pointless) research just to satisfy your curiosity.

I've added a link to the JMM spec to get you started in your (pointless) quest.   There's also a chapter in "Java Concurrency in Practice" on the JMM. Sorry, but you are just going to have to do the hard work of reading and understanding it for yourself.

I think "Java Concurrency in Practice" by Brian Goetz is the right answer here.  The OP doesn't seem to understand what even might go wrong.  Understanding the memory model is probably the missing link here.

Java Concurrency in Practice by Brian Goetz, et al.


Can anyone explain where this race condition might be happening?

TLDR: No.
The documentation for the standard JDK allows it to happen. It says,

Note that this implementation is not synchronized. If multiple threads access a hash map concurrently, and at least one of the threads modifies the map structurally, it must be synchronized externally.

https://download.java.net/java/early_access/valhalla/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html
That's all you need to know. There are no rules about what happens when you break the rules.

If I use the following ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap all problems get resolved.
private static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
Here I need to understand why we can't use HashMap, and why it not behaving correctly in multithreaded environment. Which I understood,  you answer will not help me.

@NeelabhSingh, I think you misunderstood my answer. It was not intended to help you understand why HashMap failed you.* My point is that you do not need to know why. The only thing that a software developer needs to know, is that the documentation for HashMap says you should not expect it to work if you use it in the way that your program used it. [*If you still want to know why, you can search for the source code for the OpenJDK version of HashMap, and that might give you a clue.]

Same thing I am trying to say I am not expecting Hashmap should work, Hashmap will not work here but ConcurrenlyHashMap will work here, I already mentioned this, if something is breaking you need to underfoot the root cause.

@NeelabhSingh, Forty five years as a professional software developer taught me otherwise. It taught me that, if my software fails, I don't need to know the root cause. I only need to know what mistake I made. Concurrently calling the methods of a HashMap from different threads is a mistake. If you can get rid of the problem either by using locks to prevent the concurrency, or by using a different, thread-safe data structure, then you don't need to dig any deeper. Of course, you might want to dig deeper, but in the short term, that's not what you're getting paid for.

The problem with "why" is that it is implementation dependent.  If you understand why, then tomorrow the designers of the Open JDK could change the implementation and all your understanding is suddenly wrong.  The "why" is because the external specification says so.  That's the most important part here.  You have to read and understand documentation.  If you cannot do that then your future as a software engineer is in question.

Actually, that's easy. You are checking size(). That's implemented as follows:
    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

So what happens to this field? You call put, which is implemented as follows:
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
    }

The implementation of putVal is rather long, but the only reference to the size field is:
        if (++size > threshold)
            resize();

The problem is that ++size compiles into the following bytecode sequence:
         2: getfield      #32                 // Field size:I
         5: iconst_1
         6: iadd
         7: putfield      #32                 // Field size:I

That is, we first get the field, add 1, and then store the result back. These being separate instructions without any synchronization, the following may happen:
Thread 1               Thread 2
read size -> 0    
                       read size -> 0    
add 1 -> 1
                       add 1 -> 1
write 1 to size
                       write 1 to size

Oops. The threads are overwriting each other's work.
Now, you might speculate that this would be easy to fix: Simply use an AtomicInteger. But the problem with size is just the tip of the iceberg. If you modify your test program to also look at the entries of the map:
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
        for(int i=0; i< NUM_THREADS; i++){
            executorService.execute(insertRecord());
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        int size = hashMap.size();
        int entries = 0;
        for (var e : hashMap.entrySet()) {
            entries++;
        }
        System.out.println("Size of the hashmap="+ size + " but iterating finds " + entries);

You get output like this:
Size of the hashmap=484 but iterating finds 387

So not only have we lost 16 increments to size, but we've also lost 113 mappings. The entries are stored in a field called table, which is an array containing nodes of a linked list (or tree, depending on bucket size). All those fields are read and written without any coordination, leaving plenty of opportunities for updates to be lost. For instance:

If the table is resized, a new table is created. If several threads do this at once, they'll each create a different table and overwrite the table field.
If two threads try to put a node in the same slot in the table (the same array element) at the same time, they overwrite each other's work.
If two threads try to append a node to an existing node, they may overwrite each other's work.
If a linked list is turned into a tree because it is too long, the threads may overwrite each other's work

And those are just the straightforward scenarios, there are far more. For instance, if there is a data race, a thread may observe writes in a different order than they were written. If a thread reads a reference to a node through a data race, it's possible that the fields of the node haven't been assigned yet, even if the other thread assigns the fields before storing the reference in the table, which would likely result in a NullPointerException.
Trying to account for all possible failure modes will likely make your head explode, and unless you are an expert, and likely even then, you'll likely miss the more obscure cases.
That's why sane people don't try to reason about incorrectly synchronized code, but make sure to synchronize correctly. Or as the Java Spec puts it:

If a program is correctly synchronized, then all executions of the program will appear to be sequentially consistent (§17.4.3).
This is an extremely strong guarantee for programmers. Programmers do not need to reason about reorderings to determine that their code contains data races. Therefore they do not need to reason about reorderings when determining whether their code is correctly synchronized. Once the determination that the code is correctly synchronized is made, the programmer does not need to worry that reorderings will affect his or her code.
A program must be correctly synchronized to avoid the kinds of counterintuitive behaviors that can be observed when code is reordered. The use of correct synchronization does not ensure that the overall behavior of a program is correct. However, its use does allow a programmer to reason about the possible behaviors of a program in a simple way; the behavior of a correctly synchronized program is much less dependent on possible reorderings. Without correct synchronization, very strange, confusing and counterintuitive behaviors are possible.

